# MySQL ORDER BY with GROUP BY

Tags: mysql

I have problem with this order by cdate when I use group by, the order is not the last creation date, but I think random

```
SELECT vedio_files.ID vedio_files.mCat, vedio_files.sCat,vedio_files.smalltitle, vcategories.Name,vcategories2.Name as subcat
FROM vedio_files
INNER JOIN  `vcategories` ON vedio_files.mCat = vcategories.ID 
LEFT JOIN vcategories vcategories2 ON vedio_files.sCat = vcategories2.ID
GROUP BY  vedio_files.sCat   ORDER BY vedio_files.cdate DESC LIMIT 10
```

Comment: This makes no sense: `vedio_files.ID vedio_files.mCat`

Comment: @Strawberry probably a typo. missing comma.

Comment: @JonnieJS it's not really for us to speculate, is it?

Comment: @Strawberry It's obvious -- that would cause a syntax error, but he's getting results (just not in the desired order).

Comment: @Barmar Then this obviously isn't the query.

Comment: People make copying errors all the time when posting here, you know that.

Comment: @Barmar The OP is welcome to correct the error. What's the problem?

Comment: Nothing -- just let him know that he made a typo when copying, no need to be passive-aggressive about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct.

The `ORDER BY` is applied last. That operation is *after* the `GROUP BY` collapses the rows.

The value of `cdate` on the row is indeterminate. The value is from *some* row in the group, but it's not necessarily the lowest one.

MySQL allows the query to run because of a non-standard extension to GROUP BY. (Other relational databases will throw errors about "non-aggregate expression in SELECT list not in GROUP BY". We can get MySQL to throw an error if we include `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` in sql_mode.

The behavior documented here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html

---

We can use an inline view to the minimum `cdate` for each `sCat` in `vedio_files`, and the join the results from the inline view back to `vedio_files` to get the rows with matching `sCat` and `cdate`.

Something like this:

```
SELECT vf.ID
     , vf.mCat
     , vf.sCat
     , vf.smalltitle
     , vc.Name
     , c2.Name         AS subcat
  FROM ( SELECT cd.sCat
              , MIN(cd.cdate) AS min_cdate
           FROM vedio_files cd
          GROUP
             BY cd.sCat
          ORDER
             BY MIN(cd.cdate) DESC
          LIMIT 10  
       ) mn
  JOIN vedio_files vf
    ON vf.sCat  = mn.sCat
   AND vf.cdate = mn.min_cdate  
  JOIN vcategories vc 
    ON vf.mCat = vc.ID 
  LEFT
  JOIN vcategories c2 
    ON c2.ID = vf.sCat
 ORDER
    BY ...
```

---

If there is more than one row in `vedio_files` with the same minimum date for sCat, this query return all of those rows.